# The deadly exits

Tags: riddle

A man is trapped in a room with only two exits. One exit leads into a room made of magnifying glass and instantly fries anything going into it in the hot summer sun. The other door, leads into a room with a fire breathing dragon inside. How does he escape?

I give credit for this riddle to Riddle.fyi
Sorry. I did not realise this was a duplicate.

Comment: My friend asked me this riddle before, and I answered exactly what @El-Guest did. This means the riddle might be too easy (or already heard of, especially since it is a duplicate as the above comment points out). Try to be aware of those factors, but apart from that, there is no denying (at least for me) that this is a fun riddle :)

Comment: @user477343 thank you for your pointers. I'll bear those in mind next time

Comment: Ooo, jeez, I don’t think you deserve that many downvotes. Seems a bit harsh... $(+1)$ :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to

> wait until nighttime, then leave through the magnifying glass door.

Comment: Well done. P.S. I feel that you have heard this before

Comment: No need to have heard it before. It took me about five seconds.

Comment: Ok then. Very well done

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I'm not sure if you still can, but please accept the answer if it is correct :) No worries though!

Answer (score 2):

(fun answer)

> He goes through the second door, fights the dragon a little, takes an arrow to the knee, eventually tames the dragon, and uses it's fire to burn a hole into the walls through which he finally escapes.
> This riddle is even broader than your first one, I could tell you a hundred other ways how he "could" have escaped ;)

Comment: OK, so it is very broad but i think (like you have demonstrated) it is very fun to just come up with different answers.